# EF Core Inheritance Issue

Tags: c#, inheritance, entity-framework-core

I'm working with Entity Framework Core (EF Core) and have encountered an issue related to lazy loading and inheritance. I have defined the following entity classes:

```cs
public class Pool
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Profile? Profile { get; set; }
    public int? AProfileId { get; set; }
    public int? BProfileId { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Profile
{
    public Profile() { }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class AProfile : Profile
{
    public AProfile() { }
    public virtual Pool? Pool { get; set; } 
}

public class BProfile : Profile
{
    public BProfile() { }
    public virtual Pool? Pool { get; set; } 
}

public class CProfile : Profile
{
    public CProfile() { }
    // CProfile does not have the Pool property
}

// Other profile classes
```

In my code, I've configured a relationship between `AProfile` and `Pool` using the `HasOne` method, and similarly for `BProfile`. I've also enabled lazy loading in my `OnConfiguring` method.

Here's how I've configured the relationships in the `OnModelCreating` method:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{    
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    .
    .
    .

    builder.Entity<AProfile>().HasOne(P => P.Pool).WithOne(Q => Q.Profile as AProfile).HasForeignKey<Pool>(Q => Q.AProfileId).IsRequired(false);

    builder.Entity<BProfile>().HasOne(P => P.Pool).WithOne(Q => Q.Profile as BProfile).HasForeignKey<Pool>(Q => Q.BProfileId).IsRequired(false);
}
```

However, when I retrieve a `Pool` object and try to access its `Profile` property, I notice that the `Profile` in `aPool` is null, while it should not be. The `Profile` in `bPool` works correctly.

```cs
var aPool = dbContext.Pools.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1);

Console.WriteLine($"Profile in aPool is \"{aPool.Profile}\"; aPool.AProfileId is {aPool.AProfileId}");
```

The output shows that the `Profile` in `aPool` is null, while it should not be. The `Profile` in `bPool` works correctly.
The `AProfileId` and `BProfileId` field in both scenarios has value.

I also tried the other way around. I tried adding `aProfile` to `aPool.Profile` and adding `aPool` to `context.Pools` but it raised the following error:

`System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'AProfile' cannot be tracked as the entity type 'BProfile' because the two types are not in the same hierarchy.'`

**Additional Information:**

- .NET 6.0
- Entity Framework Core version: 6.0.21
- Database provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6.0.19
- EF Core Tools version: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 6.0.19

I'm wondering why this issue is occurring and how to resolve it. Is there something specific I need to configure in EF Core to ensure that this works as expected in this inheritance scenario?

I Expect this to fill the Profile field with all of the Profile Types there.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

---

**UPDATED:**

The Problem was fixed thanks to @sorosh_sabz

**Summary of Solution Applied:**

To address the initial issue with EF Core's lazy loading and inheritance, I implemented proxy properties within the `Pool` class to handle different `Profile` types. I configured model relationships in the `OnModelCreating` method using `HasOne` and `HasForeignKey`, allowing associations between `AProfile` and `Pool`, as well as `BProfile` and `Pool`. Although this solution ensured correct database updates with foreign keys set appropriately, the retrieval of a `Pool` object elsewhere resulted in a null `Profile` field.

```cs
public class Pool
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Profile? Profile
    {
        get
        {
            return ORMAProfileAccessor as Profile ?? ORMBProfileAccessor;
        }

        set
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case AProfile aProfile:
                    ORMAProfileAccessor = aProfile;
                    break;
                case BProfile bProfile:
                    ORMBProfileAccessor = bProfile;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new InvalidCastException("Invalid profile type");
            }
        }
    }

    internal virtual AProfile? ORMAProfileAccessor { get; set; }
    internal virtual BProfile? ORMBProfileAccessor { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<AProfile>().HasOne(P => P.Pool).WithOne(Q => Q.ORMAProfileAccessor).HasForeignKey<Pool>("AProfileId").IsRequired(false);
    modelBuilder.Entity<BProfile>().HasOne(P => P.Pool).WithOne(Q => Q.ORMBProfileAccessor).HasForeignKey<Pool>("BProfileId").IsRequired(false);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Pool>().Ignore(P => P.Profile);
}
```

**New Problem:**

After implementing the suggested solution involving proxy properties and configuring relationships for inheritance in EF Core, I am still encountering an issue when retrieving a `Pool` object. Despite correct foreign keys in the database, the `Profile` field within the `Pool` object remains null. However, when retrieving a `Profile` separately, the associated `Pool` field within the `Profile` object is correctly populated.

Is there a specific configuration or additional step necessary in EF Core to ensure that when retrieving a `Pool`, the `Profile` field gets populated with the associated `Profile` type based on the foreign key relationship?

Any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/inheritance

Comment: You forgot (or didn't show) this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy#lazy-loading-with-proxies

Comment: FYI, `.NET Framework 6.0` doesn't exist. The .NET Framework term is only applicable up to .NET Framework 4.8.1. You are using .NET 6 also referred to as .NET Core 6.

Comment: You should configure the TPH inheritance in your OnModelCreating method and make sure that EF Core knows how to distinguish between different profile types.

Comment: @YasinARLI Did you can give some example for this situation in code for TPH?

Comment: I create related issue on https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/4486

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe using proxy property is adequate for this requirement

I change your `Pool` class like below

```cs
    public class Pool
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Profile? Profile
        {
            get
            {
                return ORMAProfileAccessor as Profile ?? ORMBProfileAccessor;
            }

            set
            {
                switch (value)
                {
                    case AProfile aProfile:
                        ORMAProfileAccessor = aProfile;
                        break;
                    case BProfile bProfile:
                        ORMBProfileAccessor = bProfile;
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new InvalidCastException("Invalid profile type");
                }
            }
        }

        internal virtual AProfile? ORMAProfileAccessor { get; set; }
        internal virtual BProfile? ORMBProfileAccessor { get; set; }
    }
```

and change model creation like below

```cs
            modelBuilder.Entity<AProfile>().HasOne(P => P.Pool).WithOne(Q => Q.ORMAProfileAccessor).HasForeignKey<Pool>("AProfileId").IsRequired(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<BProfile>().HasOne(P => P.Pool).WithOne(Q => Q.ORMBProfileAccessor).HasForeignKey<Pool>("BProfileId").IsRequired(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Pool>().Ignore(P => P.Profile);
```

Then we can easily using pool and profile like below

```cs
                var aProfile = new AProfile();
                var bProfile = new BProfile();
                var cProfile = new CProfile();

                var pool = new Pool
                {
                    Profile = bProfile
                };

                bProfile.Pool = pool;

                db.Add(aProfile);
                db.Add(bProfile);
                db.Add(cProfile);
                db.Add(pool);

                db.SaveChanges();

                var pool2 = db.Pools.FirstOrDefault();

                if (pool2 != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Pool2: {pool2.Id}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Pool2.Profile: {pool2.Profile?.Id}");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Feels like Pool should look like this

```
public class Pool
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual BProfile? BProfile { get; set; }
    public virtual AProfile? AProfile { get; set; }
    public int? AProfileId { get; set; }
    public int? BProfileId { get; set; }
}
```

Then your query can be written as

```
var aPool = dbContext.Pools
               .Include(s => s.AProfile)
               .Include(s => s.BProfile)
               .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1);
```

Comment: I want a general Profile parent class inside pool class.

Comment: @akshay_zz This design has one major problem, that BProfile and AProfie has exclusive in existence, and this representaiton does not OOP